# RxJavaSchedulersHook not called when using Hystrix

Tags: rx-java, hystrix

The RxJavaSchedulersHook gets used when you use the io, computation and newThread Schedulers (see the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/plugins/RxJavaSchedulersHook.html)).  When creating Observables using a HystrixCommand however, the RxJavaSchedulersHook never gets called.  This leads me to believe it may not be using one of these three schedulers.  Is there a way to have the schedulersHook get executed for Observables created from Hystrix?

Comment: To be clear, I do know that RxJava uses the RxJavaSchedulersHook and Hystrix uses the HystrixCommandExecutionHook.  What I am not clear on is which hook applies when.  When calling execute() or observe() on a command, the RxJavaSchedulersHook is not involved.  But if I were to chain two Observables (which were created from calling observe() on a command) together using flatMap(), the RxJavaSchedulersHook is called.  Can someone clarify when each is applied?